# ¿Cómo puedo buscar datos guardados en un txt con Java?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, ventana

soy nuevo aquí y por eso creo que lo primero es presentarme. Me llamo Sergio y estudio DAM (Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Multiplataforma). Bien, tengo un proyecto de final de primer curso de programación basado en ventanas, y hay ciertas cosas que me están dando problemas.
El programa es básicamente una gestión de datos de empleados, de manera que hay que crear una serie de ventanas que permitan.. jugar con los datos de los empleados (insertar, buscar y modificar). Vale, ahora bien, consigo que cuando se meten datos (en la ventana de insertar) se cree un archivo llamado Datos.txt, que va guardando los datos (Nombre, Sueldo y Sexo) de cada persona que inserto, y a la hora de volver a la ventana inicial (básicamente una visualización de datos), consigo que se vean los datos de la última persona (hasta ahí no va mal del todo). El problema viene cuando quiero buscar o modificar (para hacer esto necesitas buscar así que el problema real viene a la hora de buscar) datos de alguien, que lo que estoy utilizando busca los datos de la última persona insertada, pero no logro llegar a los datos de la persona que el usuario quiere buscar (yo le pido un nombre y es lo que uso para buscar). No se me ocurre ninguna manera de buscar en esos datos, se me ocurre guardar a cada persona en un arrayList y de ahí sacar los datos, pero entonces.. ¿para qué uso el txt a modo de.. base de datos si al final de la ejecución el arrayList del que saco los datos está vacío?
Me vendría mejor que bien una ayuda la verdad.. y gracias de antemano a todos.

PD: Voy a poner imágenes de cómo guardo los datos y cómo los leo tanto en la ventana inicial (que sí los muestra) y en la de buscar (que si no metes el nombre de la ultima persona insertada, dice que no existe).

Esta primera es el método de la ventana insertar que me guarda los datos de los empleados en el txt.

[image: Código de la ventana Insertar que me mete los datos en el .txt]

Esta segunda es la de la ventana Inicial, el método que lee el txt y saca la última persona.

[image: Ventana inicial]

Y este último es el que intento usar para buscar pero no logro que recorra el txt y encuentre el nombre y demás datos de la persona.

[image: Metodo buscar]

Oh, y que no se me olvide cómo es el txt que creo, se ve así:

[image]

Y lo dicho, que mil gracias a todos aunque sea por leerme, de verdad.

Comment: Bienvenido Serigo! Lo primero que he de recomendarte es lo siguiente, visita el [tour] para ver el funcionamiento del sitio y conseguir tu primera medalla, además te recomiendo que nunca uses capturas de pantalla, siempre pega el código. Cuanto menos mejor, pero el suficiente para que se entienda el programa y se vea tu problema, con algún ejemplo. Para modificar tu pregunta pulsa en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/172643/edit) que está justo al final de tu pregunta

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Te pido por favor que veas el [tour] y tambien [ask]. Los formalismos en este sitio no son necesarios, aunque bienvenidos. El codigo debe pegarse como codigo y no como imagen. Como tu programa es de primer curso y supongo que no habras visto base de datos, guardar en un archivo la informacion esta de mas. Supongo que con tener los datos cargados en la lista alcanzara. Y se claro con tu pregunta. En este momento no estarias preguntando nada.

Comment: Quizas sea mas facil al iniciar el programa leer todo el archivo y guardar los datos en un array de objetos.  Luego seria mas facil buscar en el array que en el archivo.

Comment: Gracias a todos, ahora entro a trabajar, cuando salga, modifico la pregunta y pego el código

Answer (score 1):

Esta pregunta no obtuvo una respuesta aquí dejare el procedimiento para recorrer un archivo de texto "Por si alguien mas tiene ese problema" y así poder encontrar un nombre dentro del txt seguido de la información que tenga abajo del nombre.

```
public void buscar() {
    File fichero = new File("C:/Users/User22/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Agenda2/DatosClientes.txt");

    String busqueda;
    String respuesta;

    try {
        BufferedReader fil = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fichero));
        String nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese un nombre para buscar", "Buscar", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        busqueda = "Nombre: " + nombre;

        String linea;
        boolean encontrado = false;
        while ((linea = fil.readLine()) != null) {

            if (linea.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(busqueda)) {

                respuesta = "Persona\n" + linea + "\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    respuesta += fil.readLine() + "\n";
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, respuesta, "Cliente encontrado!!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                encontrado = true;
                break;

            }
        }
        if (!encontrado) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Lo siento no encontramos al cliente", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un Error" + e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha producido un error", "ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```